# What is Dirichlet class number formula for d when d is NOT a fundamental discriminant?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

According to Wikipedia, Dirichlet published a proof of the class number formula for quadratic fields in 1839, but it was stated in the language of quadratic forms.

Let d be a fundamental discriminant, and write h(d) for the number of equivalence classes of quadratic forms with discriminant d.  The Dirichlet proved that h(d) is related to L(1, X) where X is the Dirichlet character associated with d.

Above is only defined when d is a fundamental discriminant. Since many numbers are NOT fundamental discriminant, is there a version of Dirichlet class number formula when d is NOT a fundamental discriminant ?

Comment: In the general case, h is still related to $L(1,\chi)$, but there are a few additional more or less well understood nonzero factors.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you explain a bit more on "nonzero factors" you mentioned ? If d  NOT a fundamental discriminant, will h(d) = 0 ?

Comment: @david: No.  There will be some non-zero factors times the non-zero number $L(1,\chi)$, so the result will again be non-zero.